# Reload Extended Drop Down

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I've a no native dropdownlist (an extended from dropdownlist) component at my page. I'm inserting data inside it on class constructor method, but now i've to refresh this data every time that I create a new object, I'm trying to use Jquery but it's not working, and i've no idea how to call the Bind method contained inside the DropDownList extended, follow the code:

Extended DropDownList:

```
public class XDDLprobabilidadesDeSucesso : XDropDownList
{
    public XDDLprobabilidadesDeSucesso()
    {
        this.DataSource = GetDataBind();
        this.DataTextField = "text";
        this.DataValueField = "id";
        this.DataBind();
    }

    private List<DDLBindType> GetDataBind()
    {
        List<DDLBindType> l = new List<DDLBindType>();
        BLLProbabilidadesSucesso probabilidade = new BLLProbabilidadesSucesso();
        List<ProbabilidadesSucesso> probabilidades = probabilidade.Retrieve().ToList();

        DDLBindType item = new DDLBindType();

        item.id = 0;
        item.text = "Selecione";
        l.Add(item);

        foreach (ProbabilidadesSucesso prob in probabilidades)
        {
            item = new DDLBindType();
            item.id = prob.idProbSucesso;
            item.text = prob.porcentagem.Value.ToString();
            l.Add(item);
        }

        return l;
    }
}
```

Can you see, the DataBind been called inside class constructor? How can i call this method another time from Jquery? (Obviouslly i've to create an public accessor)

Any answer will be usefull.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with trying to 'bind' an asp control on the client.

- The first problem is that once it is on the client it is usually a
  collection of HTML elements. The element or elements that hold the
  'bound' data may not be obvious, especially if during the bind
  process attributes are added to the elements.
- The second issue is you are not going to have any of the control
  generation script at the client. So anything you do to change its
  appearance is going to have to be done manually with a script.

So to accomplish this you would need to do the following:

First figure out how the control renders. Since this is a drop down I am assuming it renders as a `select`, unless it is some kind of image enabled drop down, in which case this is going to be more than difficult.

Once you know where the 'bound' data is going on the client, figure out how to select it. Once you have a selector that can reliably get the appropriate element or elements, ensure that you are going to be able to destroy and create the 'bound' elements.

That is to say, in the case of a `select`, make sure you can get the `select` element and that you can remove the `option` elements contained therein and replace them exactly as they are when they are 'bound' by the server.

I say to do this all first because if you are not going to be able to reliably recreate the structure of the control, then you are not going to be able to 'bind' at the client.

Once you have the selectors and methodology to recreate the control, then work on making a `webMethod` to expose the information from the page. Take a look at the page and be sure you have the information at the client required to get the information from the server to 'bind' with. You need to figure out if the server is going to require any parameters in order to gather the right information.

The `webMethod` should return the information in a way that you can easily digest it on the client. You can do this with a data table or a list of objects; anything you can iterate.

Don't worry about serializing or de-serializing, ASP will do that for you; it is cool that way. As long as you know the property names of the objects returned, then you can use the function you have now.

Once the `webMethod` is created, you then create the AJAX calls on the page to get the data to bind with. In the success call back of the ajax call to gather the data, you need to render the new information.

You need to empty the `select` and then repopulate it with `option` elements for each object in your returned data set. Again assuming the drop down renders as a `select` element.

This is roughly how I have 'bound' a bunch of gridviews and other ASP controls on the client side in order to avoid whole page post backs and refreshes.

It is not impossible but it is not super easy.